# Understanding Raw vs Unbounded Wildcard in Static Nested Class Type Definition

Tags: java, generics

I've been doing some code archeology in some odd code and I came across something similar to this:

```
public abstract class Outer<T>
{
    protected Outer(Inner<?> inner)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static abstract class Inner<U extends Outer>
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The thing that struck me was that there wasn't an unbounded wildcard type on `Inner`'s usage of the `Outer` type (the `<U extends Outer>` bit).

What is the implication of using `Inner<U extends Outer<?>>` vs. `Inner<U extends Outer>`?

I can compile and run tests successfully with both type versions, but am stumped on what is going on under the hood.

Comment: Is there a compile time warning?

Comment: Nope, no warnings for either method.

Comment: After type erasure, both signatures should be reduced to `Inner<Outer>` by my calculation.  I think the correct answer will need to show some edge cases.

Comment: If you had an assignment within `Inner` such as `U x = new OuterSubclass<Long>();`  I believe you'd get a warning about an unchecked assignment.  Where if U were a subclass of unbounded `Outer<?>`, you wouldn't. AFAIK that's the only difference.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, that's what I'm thinking too. I can't think of any edge cases that would show it other than the one @gene mentions.
The inner classes are a weird Builder "pattern", but it only uses a statically typed private field of `Outer` in a copy method:
`final Inner<U> copyFrom(Outer<?> other) {inner.field = outer.field}`.

Comment: Well the code you actually have uses `Inner<U extends Outer>` without the unbounded wildcard, so at least you don't have to dwell on the alternative scenario.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's not really an edge case.  See my answer.  TL;DR is using the raw type bypasses type checks related to the PECS principle.

Comment: @AlexMoore, let me know if anything in my answer is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Although called `Inner` in the example, it's not actually an *inner* class, but a *static nested class*.  Inner classes are non-static nested classes (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).
2. The fact that it's a static nested class instead of a top-level class doesn't matter here.
3. Code using class `Inner` can either use the raw type `Inner` (in which all type checks are bypassed - not interesting here), or specify an actual type for the type parameter `U`.  In the latter case the upper bound restricts that type to subtypes of the generic type `Outer<T>` where `T` can be any type, regardless of whether `Inner` is declared as `Inner<U extends Outer>` or `Inner<U extends Outer<?>>`.

The use of a raw type in the class signature still makes it possible to use strong type checking when declaring variables or parameters. For example, the following will compile (assuming `Inner` has a no-args constructor):

```
Outer.Inner<Outer<String>> x = new Outer.Inner<Outer<String>>();
```

But replacing `Outer<String>` on either side (but not on the other) with `Outer` will yield a compiler error.  This behavior would be exactly the same in case an unbounded wildcard would be used instead of a raw type, so **no difference so far**.

The actual difference is in how the the class `Inner` is allowed to use variables of type `U`. Suppose you are passing in such a variable in the constructor:

```
public Inner(U u) { this.u = u; }
```

Suppose also that `Outer` has a method that takes an argument of type `T` (its own type parameter), e.g.:

```
void add(T) { ...}
```

Now, in case of the raw upper bound (`U extends Outer`), it would be legal for code in class `Inner` to call this method with any object, e.g. a String:

```
this.u.add("anything")
```

although a compiler warning would be issued (unless suppressed), and in case the actual runtime type `T` would be different from `String`, a `ClassCastException` would be thrown in code that depends on the object being a different type.

In the case of an unbounded wildcard however (`U extends Outer<?>`), since `T` is a specific but unknown type, calling the `add` method will result in a compiler error regardless of which argument you give it.

Since you mention the code compiles fine in both cases, such method consuming `T` either doesn't exist in `Outer`, or it is not being called from `Inner`. But by adding the unbounded wildcard, you can **prove** to the users of the class that this is not happening (because otherwise the code wouldn't compile).

In order to allow calling `this.u.add(s)` with `s` being a `String` argument without using a raw type for the upper bound, `Inner` would have to be declared as `Inner<U extends Outer<? super String>>`, following the [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) principle, since `U` is the type of a consumer in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation!  I mix "inner" and "static nested" often, I came from C# :)
For our purposes, I don't think you could ever have/use a raw class object, so I'm going to add the unbounded wildcard where it's missing.  I don't need  to know the type parameter, but where we use it we don't care about it - we just know that it has one.